# Nesting Loops to create an american flag

Tags: c++, loops, nested

I just started learning C++, and I'm trying to use nesting loops to output an American flag. I'm very close but I cant seem to fix this logical error in my code, and was hoping someone can point it out because I've been searching for hours and its driving me crazy. The issue lies within the last three rows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int rows = 7;
int columns = 24;


int max = rows * columns;

int value = 1;
for (int r=1; r<=7; r++ ){
  for (int c=1; c<=24; c++ ){
      if (c <= 7 && r <= 4)
      cout << "* ";

      if(r % 2 != 0 && c > 7 && r > 0)
          cout << "= ";

      if(r % 2 == 0 && c > 7 && r > 0)
          cout << "- ";
}
cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

This code will output this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GN2P.png

Comment: I find it hard to read your code. The first thing i would "fix" is to rename all the variables. Also debugging will be easier once you have real names for your variables

Comment: work out which row & column is going wrong - and then step through your code at that point to work out why.

Comment: you're not outputting anything for columns <= 7 when row > 4 hence the stripes are too short

Answer (score 1):

You draw stars in the first four lines that you don't take into account afterwards.
You have to draw something when you don't draw the stars.

```
    for (int c=1; c<=24; c++ ){
        if (c <= 7 && r <= 4)
            cout << "* ";
        else {
            if(r % 2 != 0)
                cout << "= ";
            else
                cout << "- ";
        }
```

Comment: Just a style tip: the code doesn't need the curly braces after the `else`; if you remove them you can put the next `if` on the same line as the `else`, and the code will be clearer.

Comment: I find it clearer like it is. There are two condition groups: for the line and for the even/odd and they are separated. As for the curly braces,I put them always when there is more than one line after the if or else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice question for getting at the basics of combining multiple logical conditions. The question identifies three different conditions:

- in upper left corner: write '*'
- not in upper left corner, and in odd-numbered line: write '='
- not in upper left corner, and in even-numbered line: write '-'

The obvious transliteration of these conditions into code looks like this:

```
if (c <= 7 && r <= 4)
    std::cout << "* ";

if (!(c <= 7 && r <= 4) && r %2 != 0)
    std::cout << "= ";

if (!(c <= 7 && r <= 4) && r %2 == 0)
    std::cout << "- ";
```

The code in the question goes astray when it simplifies `!(c <= 7 && r <= 4)`. According to DeMorgan's law, that expression is equivalent to `!(c <= 7) || !(r <= 4)`. And that, in turn, can be simplified to `c > 7 || r > 4`. The mistake in the question is that it uses `&&` instead of `||`. I hate it when I do that. Note, too, that `&&` binds more tightly than `||`, so you have to put it in parentheses. So the simplified version looks like this:

```
if (c <= 7 && r <= 4)
    std::cout << "* ";

if ((c > 7 || r > 4) && r %2 != 0)
    std::cout << "= ";

if ((c > 7 && r > 4) && r %2 == 0)
    std::cout << "- ";
```

Not much simpler. :-(

But there's a much better version once you start thinking in C++: instead of repeating the upper-left-corner test and negating it, use an `else` clause. So

```
if (c <= 7 && r <= 4)
    std::cout << "* ";
else { /* get here when we're not in the upper left corner */
    if (r % 2 != 0)
        std::cout << "= ";
    if (r % 2 == 0);
        std::cout << "- ";
}
```

but now, note that there are two tests involving `r % 2`, one checking that it's **not** 0 and one checking that it **is** 0. That, too, should immediately say to you `if ... else ...`. So:

```
if (c <= 7 && r <= 4)
    std::cout << "* ";
else { /* get here when we're not in the upper left corner */
    if (r % 2 != 0)
        std::cout << "= ";
    else
        std::cout << "- ";
}
```

Now, as @Manuel points out, we have at the outer level two logical cases: in the upper left corner, and outside the upper left corner. That's not unreasonable, but I prefer to see this as three logical cases, as I set out the problem to begin with. To reflect that approach, get rid of the braces:

```
if (c <= 7 && r <= 4)
    std::cout << "* ";
else if (r % 2 != 0)
    std::cout << "= ";
else
    std::cout << "- ";
```